# Creating desktop/application shortcuts automatically in google chrome

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome, desktop-application, packaging

I'm creating a packaged app for Google Chrome.  I would like to create the desktop shortcuts automatically when the app is installed without having to make the user jump through loops.  Is that possible?  How can it be achieved?

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Comment: @Nilesh:  Nope it did not work :(  I dropped the idea

Comment: You can use the MSI or even better the Portable APps version of google chrome.  Wrap that in your own installer, then have it create shortcuts on the desktop .ink files with the appropriate swtiches.